# Fixed point of $f\circ f$ when $f$ is entire and not a translation

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ be entire, and not a translation ($f$ is not in the form  $a z +b$ for $a,b$ constants). Show that $f\circ f$ has a fixed point.

Can you please give me a hint, or show me the answer?
Thank you very much.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287116/the-composition-of-non-linear-entire-functions-with-no-fixed-points-has-infinite